# insert into php isn't working

Tags: php, mysqli, insert-into

I'm not that good with PHP but i need to do a user registration form and this is what I haven done so far

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
<h3>Formulario de registro</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
Usuario: <input type="text" name="login"><br />
Contrasena: <input type="password" name="password"><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br />
Sexo: <input type="text" name="sex"><br />
Edad: <input type="text" name="age"><br />
Telefono: <input type="text" name="phone"><br />
Pais: <input type="text" name="country"><br />
Ciudad: <input type="text" name="city"><br />
Direccion: <input type="text" name="address"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $login=$_POST['login'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $sex=$_POST['sex'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $country=$_POST['country'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];


    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','registro_usuarios') or die(mysql_error());

    $sql="SELECT * FROM usuario ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=0)
    {
    echo "I'm in";
    $sql="INSERT INTO usuario (login,password,email,sex,age,phone,country,city,address)
    VALUES('$login','$password','$password','$email','$sex','$age','$country','$city','$address')";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


    if($result){
    echo "Account Successfully Created";
    } else {
    echo "Failure!";
    }

    } else {
    echo "That username already exists! Please try again with another.";
    }

} else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I can see the message "I'm in" in my screen but I'm also get the "Failure" message because it's not inserting anything into the the database. I have been struggling trying to find the error but nothing so far. The error should be around here

```
$sql="INSERT INTO usuario (login,password,email,sex,age,phone,country,city,address)
    VALUES('$login','$password','$password','$email','$sex','$age','$country','$city','$address')";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

I have checked all the values from my database in case of a typo just in case you guys wonder and there is no typo.

Thanks

Comment: Thank goodness it isn't working -- your code is completely wide open to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)!

Comment: replace with this line VALUES('$login','$password','$email','$sex','$age','$phone','$country','$city','$address')";   I wrote twice the value password but still nothing

Comment: What about `$phone`?

Comment: Yeah i corrected that like i said in my comment, but still nothing

Comment: this is a typo question; look at your code again, very carefully

Comment: Look at your INSERT INTO.  the VALUES do not match the INSERT INTO fields.  Twice $password, no $phone.

Answer (score 0):

You wrong in sql insert.

your sql :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO usuario (login,password,email,sex,age,phone,country,city,address) VALUES('$login','$password','$password','$email','$sex','$age','$country','$city','$address')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

look at the value row doesn't match with the insert fields. You insert twice $password, and no $phone.

If still error, you can add this to know what wrong with your query:

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   echo 'Success'.'</br>';
}
else
{
   echo 'Fail';
   echo "Error Description : ".mysqli_error($con);
}
```